# Azure VIP SWAP - What really happens behind the scene

Tags: azure

Could someone please help me understand what exactly means VIP SWAP?

Let say Production slot with Deployment ID D1 has VIP 1.2.3.4 and Staging slot with Deployment ID D2 has 5.6.7.8.

After VIP swap does Production Slot becomes 5.6.7.8? Or Production slot VIP remains same but it points the D2 and Staging Slot points to D1?

Answer (score 1):

**(EDIT)**

Concrete answer:

> Production becomes 5.6.7.8. It is IP Address SWAP, not a Deployment
>   Slot SWAP!

Please take a look at [this article](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/03/windows-azure-basics-part-2-of.html) I've written a while ago. If you look at the picture:

[image]

there is Load Balancer with VIP. Imagine you have two of these pictures with VIP2 and VIP2. VIP Swap is exactly what its name suggest - swapping the (public) IP Addresses of the Load Balancers in front of the two deployments.

Comment: After VIP swap does Production Slot becomes 5.6.7.8? Or Production slot VIP remains same but it points the D2 and Staging Slot points to D1?

Comment: This is the wrong answer. The production IP remains the same.

Comment: well, depends how you look at it. More info on the official documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-swap-deployment

P.S. do you really still use Cloud Services? ;)